# What is the meaning of `jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` and does it create a security issue?

Tags: authentication, jenkins, terminal

I saw this is a way to resolve jenkins build script upload to aws instance issue with authentication, bu what exactly this mean? how should I execute it? I can't execute it in terminal as jenkins is a command not found, but I do have Jenkins running in local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Means to run `ALL` commands without a password for a user named `jenkins`.

And is a syntax/configuration for the program [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) which basically allows users to run programs with the security privileges of another user, by default the superuser.

It definitely creates a security issue but you need to find a way to deal with it since it is giving "root" privileges to the user.

You can read more about `sudo` ([sudoers](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html)) here: https://www.sudo.ws/intro.html